# Reading barcode in datawindow (powerbuilder)

Tags: barcode, powerbuilder, pos

I have like a POS application where I work, and I added new code to read barcodes in a datawindow, but been having some problems to use it correctly. The process needs to read the barcode and automatically search for the product, and insert it in another datawindow with the info regarding the product.
The problem is that I have the code in the editchanged event, and that the barcodes have different lenght; so, every time a number of the barcode is read, the search function is called, here is the code for that function:

```
ll_rtn = dw_search.Retrieve()

If ll_rtn = 1 Then
    is_code = dw_search.GetItemString(1,'barcode')
    wf_insert(False)
End If
```

If for example, a product of 10 digits is read and at length 5 the product is found, it's inserted but the editchanged is still running because the barcode is length 10, and depends of the search, might find it again with the last digits and insert it again.
I don't  know how to stop reading after I find the product. Hope I explain it right.

Answer (score 2):

Can you check if the barcode scanner can be configured to pass carriage return / Enter, upon scanning the barcode and this way you can move your code to itemchanged event

[Bar Code Config](https://amberpos.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/215979843-Adding-an-Enter-Key-Carriage-Return-to-the-Motorola-LS2208-Barcode-Scanner)

Comment: I'll check the scanner manual, didn't know that was an option.

Answer (score 1):

An editchanged event is fired for each keystroke in the control.  You probably want to either move the code to the itemchanged event or to a totally separate event which is posted from the itemchanged event.

If you absolutely have to have the code in the editchanged event you need to set a boolean instance variable on the window which is set TRUE once the product is found.  If it's true then don't search.  Remember to reset the variable to FALSE prior to any new search.

Comment: I tried the itemchanged event, but in order to trigger the event it need a feedback from the user, like enter or tab (and the user refuses the accept to give feedback, says it need to be automatic).
I tried to losefocus after the product was found, but at some point I need to give back the focus automatically so it can search again.